# Apple TV simulator - Siri Remote not appearing

Tags: ios-simulator, tvos-simulator

Sometimes when using the Apple TV simulator, the simulated Siri Remote goes missing. Toggling it's visibility does nothing - it's extremely frustrating!

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This happens when you are using external monitors. To bring it back, use the command line to reset the position of the remote:

```
defaults delete com.apple.iphonesimulator "NSWindow Frame Apple TV Remote Window"
```

Then, re-launch `Simulator.app`, open a TV and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> again!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else looking for the "Apple TV Remote", it has been moved to the "Window" menu.

Or you can simply use the shortcut (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>) as Max mentioned.

[image]